# User registration in python using socket

Tags: python, android

I'm doing an internship project in which I have to register the user in particular the user takes the photo from android studio this photo is sent to the python server which generates the biometric key and this is sent to the python code which inserts it into the databases.

The problem is that if I have two photos of the same face, different keys are generated, how can I avoid this?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os
import sys
from socket import *

""" PARAMETRI INIZIALI """
zm_fc = 0.50
TCP_IP = "100.101.0.100"  # Indirizzo IP del server
T_PORT = 65535  # Porta del server

socket_tcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
socket_tcp.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
socket_tcp.bind((TCP_IP, T_PORT))
socket_tcp.listen(1)

def receiveImage(conn):
    try:
        with open('/Users/Bia/Desktop/ReceivedImage.png', 'wb') as img:
            # Ricevi la dimensione dell'array di byte all'inizio del flusso
            size_bytes = conn.recv(4)
            image_size = int.from_bytes(size_bytes, byteorder='big')

            # Ricevi l'immagine
            remaining_size = image_size
            while remaining_size > 0:
                data = conn.recv(min(1024, remaining_size))
                if not data:
                    # Se non ci sono più dati da ricevere, esci dal ciclo
                    break
                img.write(data)
                remaining_size -= len(data)

        print("Immagine ricevuta dal dispositivo Android")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Errore durante la ricezione dell'immagine:", str(e))

def sendKey(key, conn):
    try:
        if key is not None:
            conn.send(key.encode())
            print("Chiave biometrica inviata al dispositivo Android")
        else:
            # Se il volto non è stato rilevato, invia un messaggio di "NO_FACE_DETECTED"
            conn.send("NO_FACE_DETECTED".encode())
            print("Nessun volto rilevato. Invio del messaggio di 'NO_FACE_DETECTED'")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Errore durante l'invio della chiave biometrica:", str(e))
    finally:
        conn.close()

def get_frame():
    try:
        frame = face_recognition.load_image_file('/Users/Bia/Desktop/ReceivedImage.png')
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)

        if len(face_locations) > 0:
            print("Volto rilevato.")
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame, face_locations)
            return True, face_encodings[0]
        else:
            print("Nessun volto rilevato.")
            return False, None

    except Exception as e:
        print("Errore in get_frame:", str(e))
        return False, None

def start():
    try:
        ret, face_encoding = get_frame()
        if ret and face_encoding is not None:
            print("Chiave biometrica generata:", str(face_encoding))
            return str(face_encoding)
        else:
            print("Nessun volto rilevato.")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("Errore nella generazione della chiave biometrica:", str(e))
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("In attesa del dispositivo Android ...")

    while True:
        conn, addr = socket_tcp.accept()

        print("Connessione con il dispositivo Android stabilita. Pronto per ricevere l'immagine")
        receiveImage(conn)
        print("Generazione della chiave biometrica in corso ...")

        chiave_biometrica = start()
        if chiave_biometrica is not None:
            print("La chiave biometrica è stata generata:", chiave_biometrica)
            print("Invio della chiave al dispositivo Android ...")
            sendKey(chiave_biometrica, conn)
            conn.close()  # Chiudo la connessione dopo aver inviato la chiave
            
        else:
            print("Nessun volto rilevato. Si prega di reinserire le informazioni dell'utente.")
            chiave_messaggio = "NO_FACE_DETECTED"

            # Chiudo la connessione prima di inviare il messaggio
            conn.close()

            # Creo una nuova connessione per inviare il messaggio
            conn, addr = socket_tcp.accept()
            conn.send(chiave_messaggio.encode())

            conn.close()
```